# Allow alphabet characters to be the only inputs into entrybox tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

#Want this code but to only allow str (alphabet)

```py
def is_type_int(*args):
      item = var2.get()
      try:
        item_type = type(int(item))
        if item_type == type(int(1)):
            #Had too have any action here so just made a print do nothing
            print 
      except:
        IDEntry.delete(0, tk.END)
var2 = tk.StringVar()
var2.trace("w", is_type_int)
```

Comment: FYI, you can use `pass` to do nothing

Answer (score 0):

So, the first option I was thinking about it to compare the type to str instead of int. But this solution would not always work because it depends on how the argument is passed.

I'd try to use regex instead, use a simple function to check if there is any number in the input text as below:

```
   import re


def numberInText(input_string):
    # Using regex, look for a number in the string
    if (re.search("[0-9]",input_string)):
        return True
    # if no number is found, return False
    return False

test_with_number = "TEST 123"

print(numberInText(test_with_number))

test_without_number = "TEST"
print(numberInText(test_without_number))
```

Comment: I want it to stop all inputs going into the entry box on my form in the first place unless they are alphabet

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible using tkinter. You could handle such cases by validating the entry and provide a red comment under the text field.

Comment: It is with the code I posted. Just not for str.

Comment: Ok and I provided the function to check if a string contains a number. Just use the function instead of checking if the type is int.